# rotating image (Base64) during upload from mobile camera

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, base64

I have upload and crop image script. 
everything is working fine, but when i try to upload image from mobile camera it rotating.

Please see below the code.

maybe you can tell me where i was wrong and how to fix this rotation.

```
var CROP = (function () {

    return function () {

        // Code Dependant Variables
        this.eles = {
            ele: undefined,
            container: undefined,
            img: undefined,
            overlay: undefined,
            preview: undefined
        };

        this.img = undefined;
        this.imgInfo = {
            aw: 0,
            ah: 0,
            w: 0,
            h: 0,
            at: 0,
            al: 0,
            t: 0,
            l: 0,
            s: 1 // scale
        };

        this.init = function(ele) {

            $(ele.container)
                .attr({
                    'data-imgcrop': '',
                    'data-mask': ele.mask
                })
                .append('<input type="range" value="'+ele.zoom.min+'" min="'+ele.zoom.min+'" max="'+ele.zoom.max+'" step="'+ele.zoom.steps+'"><div class="cropMain"></div>');

            // set min zoom
            this.imgInfo.s = ele.zoom.min;


            /*
                Elements
            */
            var umm = ele,
                shell = $(ele.container),
                zoom = shell.find('input'),
                cropMain = shell.find('.cropMain'),
                cropPreview = ele.preview,
                img,
                container,
                overlay,
                that = this;


            /*
                Container
            */
            container = $('<div />')
                .attr({
                class: 'crop-container'
            })
                .css({
                width: ele.width + 'px',
                height: ele.height + 'px'
            });

            /*
                Image
            */
            img = $('<img />')
                    .attr('class', 'crop-img')
                    .css({
                        zIndex: 5999,
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0
                    });




            /*
                Crop Overlay
            */
            overlay = $('<div />')
                .attr({
                class: 'crop-overlay',
                draggable: "true"
            })
                .css({
                zIndex: 6000
            });


            // Add Elements
            container.append(overlay);
            container.append(img);
            cropMain.append(container);

            this.eles.ele = cropMain;
            this.eles.container = container;
            this.eles.img = img;
            this.eles.overlay = overlay;
            this.eles.preview = cropPreview;

            // load image
            this.loadImg(ele.image);


            /*
                Bind Events
            */
            container.resize(function () {
                that.imgSize();
            });


            /*
                Overlay Movement
            */
            overlay.bind(((document.ontouchstart !== null) ? 'mousedown' : 'touchstart'), function (e) {

                // apply grab cursor
                $('body').addClass('grabcursor');

                var o = $(this),
                    mousedown = {
                        x: (e.originalEvent.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX),
                        y: (e.originalEvent.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY)
                    },
                    elepos = {
                        x: o.parent().offset().left,
                        y: o.parent().offset().top
                    };

                e.preventDefault();


                $(document).bind(((document.ontouchmove !== null) ? 'mousemove' : 'touchmove'), function (e) {


                    var mousepos = {
                        x: (e.originalEvent.pageX || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX || mousedown.x),
                        y: (e.originalEvent.pageY || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY || mousedown.y)
                    };


                    if (mousedown.y !== mousepos.y) {

                        if (parseInt(o.css('top')) === 0) o.css({
                            top: that.eles.ele.offset().top,
                            left: that.eles.ele.offset().left
                        });

                        // Move Image
                        that.imgMove({
                            t: parseInt(o.css('top')) - (elepos.y - (mousedown.y - mousepos.y)),
                            l: parseInt(o.css('left')) - (elepos.x - (mousedown.x - mousepos.x))
                        });

                        // Reposition Overlay
                        o.css({
                            left: elepos.x - (mousedown.x - mousepos.x),
                            top: elepos.y - (mousedown.y - mousepos.y)
                        });

                    }

                });

                $(document).bind(((document.ontouchend !== null) ? 'mouseup' : 'touchend'), function (e) {

                    // remove grab cursor
                    $('body').removeClass('grabcursor');

                    $(document).unbind(((document.ontouchmove !== null) ? 'mousemove' : 'touchmove'));
                    overlay.css({
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0
                    });
                });

                return false;
            });


            //  config slide
            // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

            $('input[type=range]').on("input change", function () {

                that.slider(zoom.val());

                rangeColor(zoom);

            });

            that.zoom = function(num) {

                if(num === 'min' || num === 'max')
                    var num = parseInt(zoom.attr(num));

                that.slider(num);
                zoom.val(num);
                rangeColor(zoom);

            };


            // zoom slider progress color
            function rangeColor(self) {

                var val = self.val(),
                    min = self.attr('min'),
                    max = self.attr('max'),
                    pos = Math.round(((val - min) / (max - min)) * 100),
                    style = "background: linear-gradient(to right, #fbc93d " + pos + "%, #eee " + (pos + 0.1) + "%);";

                // apply background color to range progress
                self.attr('style', style);

            }

        };

        this.loadImg = function (url) {
            var that = this;

            this.eles.img.removeAttr('style').attr('src', url)
                .load(function () {
                that.imgSize();
            });
        };

        this.imgSize = function () {
            var img = this.eles.img,
                imgSize = {
                    w: img.css('width', '').width(),
                    h: img.css('height', '').height()
                },
                c = this.eles.container;

            var holderRatio = {
                wh: this.eles.container.width() / this.eles.container.height(),
                hw: this.eles.container.height() / this.eles.container.width()
            };

            this.imgInfo.aw = imgSize.w;
            this.imgInfo.ah = imgSize.h;

            if (imgSize.w * holderRatio.hw < imgSize.h * holderRatio.wh) {

                this.imgInfo.w = c.width();
                this.imgInfo.h = this.imgInfo.w * (imgSize.h / imgSize.w);
                this.imgInfo.al = 0;

            } else {

                this.imgInfo.h = c.height();
                this.imgInfo.w = this.imgInfo.h * (imgSize.w / imgSize.h);
                this.imgInfo.at = 0;
            }

            this.imgResize();
        };


        this.imgResize = function (scale) {

            var img = this.eles.img,
                imgInfo = this.imgInfo,
                oldScale = imgInfo.s;

            imgInfo.s = scale || imgInfo.s;

            img.css({
                width: imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s,
                height: imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s
            });

            // Move Image Based on Size Changes
            this.imgMove({
                t: -((imgInfo.h * oldScale) - (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s)) / 2,
                l: -((imgInfo.w * oldScale) - (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s)) / 2
            });
        };

        this.imgMove = function (move) {

            var img = this.eles.img,
                imgInfo = this.imgInfo,
                c = this.eles.container;

            imgInfo.t += move.t;
            imgInfo.l += move.l;

            var t = imgInfo.at - imgInfo.t,
                l = imgInfo.al - imgInfo.l;


            if (t >= 0) t = imgInfo.t = 0;

            else if (t < -((imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s) - c.height())) {
                t = -((imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s) - c.height());
                imgInfo.t = ((imgInfo.at === 0) ? (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s) - c.height() : (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s) - c.height());
            }

            if (l >= 0) l = imgInfo.l = 0;

            else if (l < -((imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s) - c.width())) {
                l = -((imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s) - c.width());
                imgInfo.l = ((imgInfo.al === 0) ? (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s) - c.width() : (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s) - c.width());
            }

            // Set Position
            img.css({
                top: t,
                left: l
            });


            if(this.eles.preview)
                this.preview(this.eles.preview.width, this.eles.preview.height, this.eles.preview.container);

        };



        /*
            Slider
        */
        this.slider = function (slideval) {

            this.imgResize(slideval);

        };




        //  return cropped data: coordinates & base64 string
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        this.data = function(width, height, filetype) {

            var self = this,
                imgInfo = self.imgInfo,
                c = self.eles.container,
                img = self.eles.img;

            var original = new Image();
                original.src = img.attr('src');

            // draw image to canvas
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;

            var w = Math.round((c.width() - (0 * 2)) * (imgInfo.aw / (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s))),
                h = Math.round((c.height() - (0 * 2)) * (imgInfo.ah / (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s))),
                x = Math.round(-(parseInt(img.css('left')) - 0) * (imgInfo.aw / (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s))),
                y = Math.round(-(parseInt(img.css('top')) - 0) * (imgInfo.ah / (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s)));

            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(original, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, width, height);

            data = {
                width: width,
                height: height,
                image: canvas.toDataURL("image/"+filetype),
                filetype: filetype
            };

            return data;
        };



        //  show preview
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        this.preview = function(width, height, target) {

            var self = this,
                imgInfo = self.imgInfo,
                c = self.eles.container,
                img = self.eles.img;

            // if #preview element doesn't exist, create
            if(!$(target + ' img').length)
                $(target)
                    .css({
                        'height': c.height(),
                        'width': c.width(),
                        'overflow':'hidden',
                        'margin':'0 auto',
                        'padding':0,
                        'transform': 'scale('+this.eles.preview.ratio+')',
                    })
                    .append('<img>');

            // position and resize image
            $(target + ' img')
                .attr('src', img.attr('src'))
                .attr('style', 'position:relative;' + $('.crop-img').attr('style'));

        };



        //  flip image
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        this.flip = function() {

            var self = this,
                imgInfo = self.imgInfo,
                c = self.eles.container,
                img = self.eles.img;

            // get current width & height
            var original = new Image();
                original.src = img.attr('src');
                height = original.naturalHeight;
                width = original.naturalWidth;

            canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;

            canvas.getContext('2d').translate(width, 0);
            canvas.getContext('2d').scale(-1, 1);
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(original, 0, 0);
            canvas.getContext('2d').translate(width, 0);
            canvas.getContext('2d').scale(-1, 1);

            c.find('.crop-img')
                .removeAttr('style')
                .attr('src', canvas.toDataURL());

        };



        //  rotate 90 degrees
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        this.rotate = function() {

            var self = this,
                imgInfo = self.imgInfo,
                c = self.eles.container,
                img = self.eles.img;

            // get current width & height
            var original = new Image();
                original.src = img.attr('src');
                height = original.naturalHeight;
                width = original.naturalWidth;

            canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = height;
            canvas.height = width;

            canvas.getContext('2d').translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
            canvas.getContext('2d').rotate(Math.PI / 2);
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(original, -width / 2, -height / 2);
            canvas.getContext('2d').rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
            canvas.getContext('2d').translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);

            c.find('.crop-img')
                .removeAttr('style')
                .attr('src', canvas.toDataURL());

        };



        //  download image
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        this.download = function(width, height, filename, filetype, link) {

            var self = this,
                imgInfo = self.imgInfo,
                c = self.eles.container,
                img = self.eles.img;

            var original = new Image();
                original.src = img.attr('src');

            // draw image to canvas
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;

            var w = Math.round((c.width() - (0 * 2)) * (imgInfo.aw / (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s))),
                h = Math.round((c.height() - (0 * 2)) * (imgInfo.ah / (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s))),
                x = Math.round(-(parseInt(img.css('left')) - 0) * (imgInfo.aw / (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s))),
                y = Math.round(-(parseInt(img.css('top')) - 0) * (imgInfo.ah / (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s)));

            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(original, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, width, height);

            $('#' + link)
                .attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/"+filetype))
                .attr('download', filename + '.' + filetype);

        };



        //  import new image
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        this.import = function() {

            $('body').append('<input type="file" id="importIMG" style="display:none">');

            var self = this,
                imgInfo = self.imgInfo,
                c = self.eles.container,
                img = self.eles.img;

            oFReader = new FileReader(), rFilter = /^(image\/bmp|image\/gif|image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/tiff)$/i;


            $('#importIMG').change(function() {

                if(document.getElementById("importIMG").files.length === 0) return;
                var oFile = document.getElementById("importIMG").files[0];
                if(!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) return;
                oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);

                $('#importIMG').remove();

            });

            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {

                c.find('.crop-img')
                    .removeAttr('style')
                    .attr('src', oFREvent.target.result);

            };

            $('#importIMG').click();

        };

    };

}());
```

Comment: Are you sure it's during the upload and not during the capturing ?

Comment: When i use PC everything working fine. 
but when i use mobile camera and take a pic (vertical orientation) it rotate image. when i use horizontal orientation it doesn't rotate it

Comment: Yes but does it also render like so before the upload ? Also, note that there are currently some close-votes pending on this question asking for an [MCVE] (note the **Minimal**)

Comment: Maybe it's already resolved, but I found the same problem with an image upload plugin. The problem lies in the exif orientation: some cameras do not rotate the image from the sensor, they keep it as it is (landscape) and write the EXIF Orientation tag. You should try to read it and rotate accordingly (usually the Orientation tag value is '6', that is "Rotate 90 Clockwise")